# Read CAD files in C++ program

Tags: library, c++, visual-studio, cad, cam

I am currently looking for a library which allows me to read CAD files. The type of the file does not matter (.STL, .DWG, etc). The goal is to extract the maximum height, widht and depth of the object. Until now I found

- LibDWG
- libopencad

I want to develop the program in C++/VS15. 
Any help is appreciated. Niko

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for has a [C/C++ Vector library](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/vector) that might help you with this.

You can use the [L_VecLoadFile function](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/vector/api/l-vecloadfile.html) to open different types of files, including DWG, DXF, SVG, DGN, GBR and [many others](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/formats#vector).

You can then use the [L_VecEnumObjects function](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/vector/api/l-vecenumobjects.html) to obtain all the vector objects inside the loaded file. For each object, you can use any of the various functions in the library to examine that object’s properties. For example the [L_VecGetObjectParallelogram function](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/vector/api/l-vecgetobjectparallelogram.html) gives you the parallelogram that contains the specified object, including 2 points that represent the minimum and maximum 3-D points of the bounding parallelogram.

If you would like to try it, there’s [a free evaluation edition of LEADTOOLS you can download](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main). The evaluation comes with demos source code for C/C++, and free technical support.